# What is the memory limit on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, ram, 32-bit

I'm new to Linux and was wondering if it had any limit. Windows has limit 32bit-4GB, 64bit-128GB or so. Does the 32bit version of Ubuntu have a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every computer system has limits. 2<sup>32</sup> is 4,294,967,296. (4294967296/(1024*1024)) is 4096 (e.g. 4 GB). However, Linux has (or had) support for [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) which allows for up to 64 GB. At the moment, the limit on 64-bits is around 2<sup>46</sup> bits, which is 67,108,864 GB (or 64 [PB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte)).

Comment: Every 32 bit computer system had this limit.